# Remove distinct row if NULL column exists from SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of transactions,

```
History[CustomerID, BikeID,Checkout,StationIDout,Checkin,StationIDin]
```

where `Checkout` and `Checkin` are `GETDATE()`

**I want to query `History` so that I receive bikes that are currently at a given StationID, (i.e. `Checkin` and `StationIDin` are `NOT NULL`)**

I am currently using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BikeID from History
where StationIDin = {0} 
AND Checkin IS NOT NULL AND StationIDin IS NOT NULL
```

Not surprisingly, I am still receiving bikes that are checked out, because my query picks out the first `BikeID` it sees with a completed transaction without searching for another instance where the same bike is NOT checked back in.

I would like to form a query that does **NOT** select `BikeID` that are checked out. In other words, to search for any occurrence of NULL in StationIDin and eliminate it from the result before selecting the `BikeID`.

(My apologies for potentially misnaming the title, I can't describe it better)

```
CustomerID  BikeID   Checkout   StationIDout   Checkin   StationIDin
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1001          32     6/8/16       500          6/28/16       500
1002          21     1/2/15       500          1/3/15        500
1003          32     3/7/15       500           NULL         NULL

CURRENT OUTPUT:
32
21

DESIRED OUTPUT:
21
```

Comment: can you post some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: You keep all the data in a single table and this is not the right way to do it. And is error prone. Reconsider your design, keep the current status of each bike in a table and its history in a different table. In the current status table each bike must appear exactly once. In the history table a bike can appear zero or more times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`, not `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT BikeID 
FROM History h
WHERE StationIDin = {0} 
GROUP BY BikeId
HAVING SUM(CheckIn IS NULL) = 0;
```

This returns all bikes that have no record with `CheckIn` as `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a self-join to filter out results that match the bike ID and they're not checked in.

```
SELECT DISTINCT h1.BikeID
FROM History AS h1
LEFT JOIN History AS h2 ON h1.BikeID = h2.BikeID AND (h2.Checkin IS NULL OR h2.StationIDin IS NULL)
WHERE h1.Checkin IS NOT NULL AND h2.StationIDin IS NOT NULL
AND h2.BikeID IS NULL
```